# Remove wrapping tags for images

Tags: php, regex, ckeditor, preg-replace

I have a CKeditor outputting some tags around the images. So far I'm using a regex to get rid of those wraping tags.

Here are some test strings:

```
$example1 = '<p data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" style="text-align: center;"><span><img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620" /><span title="Click and drag to resize">•</span></span></p>';
$example2 = '<p><img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620" /></p>';
$example3 = '<html>
<head></head>
<body>
some text here...
<p><img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620" />
</p>
</body>
</html>';
// Wanted result : <html><head></head><body>some text here...<img alt="julie-bishop.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/julie-bishop.jpg" width="620" /></body></html>
```

The regex I tried is `/(.*?)<p>\s*(<img[^<]+?)\s*<\/p>(.*)/`, this works perfectly with the example2.

```
preg_replace("/(.*?)<p>\s*(<img[^<]+?)\s*<\/p>(.*)/", "$1$2$3", $string);
```

The rule is : If you detect a <p> with <img> as one of its children then keep the <img> and remove the <p> and its OTHER children (can be span or something else...)

Any idea how to achieve what I need ?

Comment: Why not use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). It was designed for the purpose of navigating `XML` documents

Comment: @gwillie Thought about it, but for performance purposes and for simplicity, I think regex is more adapted to this issue. I'm not intending to do some complex structure changes on the DOM just remove the wrapping tags for images

Comment: Then why not use `preg_match('~<img .+?/>~',$example1, $matches);`

Comment: @gwillie not exactly what I expect, otherwise it would have been too easy. I think my 2 examples are bit confusing, I added another one to explain better the situation. The example I gave were out of context.

Comment: But the regex works the same, regardless of `$example3`, it'll still match beginning to end of a single `img` element. Every element is 'wrapped' by another, the highest being `<html>`. Are you saying you want to remove eg `<p>`, or `<span>`...an element that directly surrounds `<img`>.

Comment: @gwillie yes that's my objective, I just realised that it is much more complicated than a simple regex. I know the rule it's just that I don't know how to transform it into regex. The rule is : If you detect a <p> with <img> as one of it's children then keep the <img> and remove the <p> and it's OTHER children (can be span or something else...)

Comment: if you must use regex then you could just search for `<p>` or `<span>` wrapping `<img>`, eg `~<(?:p|span).*?><img .+?/></(?:p|span)>~`, then you just extract `<img>` as shown before.

Comment: @113408 regular expressions are **NOT** for parsing HTML/XML. Get rid of that `preg_replace` and have a look at `DOMDocument`. It's more simple than you think.

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove `<p>`<img ...>`</p>` tags and keep the img?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex :

```
<p(?:[^>]*|\r\n|\n)>(?:.*|\r\n|\n)(<img(?:[^>]*|\r\n|\n)>)(?:.*|\r\n|\n)<\/p>
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bg0Xq4/1/) on regex101.com

And here is a [working demo](https://eval.in/789512) in eval.in (your PHP code)

Comment: Works well on the tests I've run and pretty straight-forward !

Answer (score 0):

It is not using regexp but it can be done more readable way if you use any xml parser like DOM.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - a popular quote by
>   Jamie Zawinski:

you can use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php to load the html fragment. then can use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php to fetch all the `<p>`. Once you get the Node list of `<p>` tag you can loop through each of the the node.

on each `<p>` node use use  then can use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php to find any `<img>` tag. if any is found you can use `$node->childNodes` to get children of each `<p>` node. loop through and use http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php to remove the children node other than `<img>` node. once done you can use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php to get the processed html back.

Comment: When you quote people it looks like you give credence and importance to the content of the quote. In this case, you seem to be quoting someone who doesn't have a clue about what regular expressions are. Basically, a fool in the sense his quote is about regex.

Comment: I understand that regex can be complicated sometimes, but once you master it it solves lot of issues. In my case there is no need to handle the DOM as what I try to achieve is just striping specific tags

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are applying is not good instead of `REGEX` you should use `DOMDocument`. Here we are using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`. I hope my solution will help you out and surely fix your issue.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$example1 = '<p data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" style="text-align: center;"><span><img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620" /><span title="Click and drag to resize">•</span></span></p>';
$example2 = '<p><img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620" /></p>';
$example3 = '<html>
<head></head>
<body>
some text here...
<p><img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620" />
</p>
</body>
</html>';


$domDocument= new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($example1,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$domXPath=new DOMXPath($domDocument);

if($domXPath->query("//html")->length)
{
    foreach($domXPath->query("//p") as $pelement)
    {
        if($domXPath->query("//img",$pelement)->length)
        {
            $pelement->parentNode->replaceChild(getReplacement($domXPath),$pelement);
        }
    }
    echo $pelement->ownerDocument->saveHTML();
}
else
{
    echo getReplacement($domXPath,true);
}

function getReplacement($domXPath,$string=false)
{
    global $domDocument;
    $results=$domXPath->query('//p');
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        if($innerNodes=$domXPath->query("//img",$result->childNodes->item(0)))
        {
            if($string===true)
            {
                return $domDocument->saveHTML($result->childNodes->item(0));
            }
            else 
            {
                return $result->childNodes->item(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output for string1:**

`<span><img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620"><span title="Click and drag to resize">Ã¢Â€Â¢</span></span>`

**Output for string2:**

`<img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620">`

**Output for string3:**

`<html>
<head></head>
<body>
some text here...
<img alt="image.jpg" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="349" src="image.jpg" width="620">
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Since only *TAGS* are involved, and specifically adjacent tags `<p><img../></p>`
it can be easily done with regex.

The problem is all tags have to be matched and skipped if not involved in
the sequence above.

The reason all tags have to be matched is that tags can be hidden inside
hidden content *and* comments.

But, php gives you the power of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` backtracking control verbs
which enables matching, but more importantly, *skipping* the other tags
and hidden content, without coming out of the regex in the form of a match.

And, when put together with a couple of atomic groups, the speed is good.

This result shows 50 iterations times 130K html source =  6.5 MB of html in 2/3 second.

```
Regex1:   (?><p\s*>\s*(<img\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?>)\s*</p\s*>)|(?><(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\2\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.68 s,   683.32 ms,   683318 µs
```

https://regex101.com/r/CCyNZ5/1

Find (stringed):

`'~(?><p\s*>\s*(<img\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|[^>]?)+\s*/?>)\s*</p\s*>)|(?><(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\2\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)~'`

Replace `$1`

[Formatted](http://regexformat.com)

```
     # Just '<p><img../></p>'
     (?>
          <p \s* >
          \s* 
          (                             # (1 start)
               <img
               \s+ 
               (?:
                    " [\S\s]*? " 
                 |  ' [\S\s]*? ' 
                 |  [^>]? 
               )+
               \s* /?
               >
          )                             # (1 end)
          \s* 
          </p \s* >
     )

  |  # Or,

     # Skip all other tags and invisible content
     (?>
          <
          (?:
               (?:
                    (?:
                                                       # Invisible content; end tag req'd
                         (                             # (2 start)
                              script
                           |  style
                           |  object
                           |  embed
                           |  applet
                           |  noframes
                           |  noscript
                           |  noembed 
                         )                             # (2 end)
                         (?:
                              \s+ 
                              (?>
                                   " [\S\s]*? "
                                |  ' [\S\s]*? '
                                |  (?:
                                        (?! /> )
                                        [^>] 
                                   )?
                              )+
                         )?
                         \s* >
                    )

                    [\S\s]*? </ \2 \s* 
                    (?= > )
               )

            |  (?: /? [\w:]+ \s* /? )
            |  (?:
                    [\w:]+ 
                    \s+ 
                    (?:
                         " [\S\s]*? " 
                      |  ' [\S\s]*? ' 
                      |  [^>]? 
                    )+
                    \s* /?
               )
            |  \? [\S\s]*? \?
            |  (?:
                    !
                    (?:
                         (?: DOCTYPE [\S\s]*? )
                      |  (?: \[CDATA\[ [\S\s]*? \]\] )
                      |  (?: -- [\S\s]*? -- )
                      |  (?: ATTLIST [\S\s]*? )
                      |  (?: ENTITY [\S\s]*? )
                      |  (?: ELEMENT [\S\s]*? )
                    )
               )
          )
          >
     )
     (*SKIP)(*FAIL)
```

Comment: This regex only works when <img> is direct child of <p> which is not always the case for me